# How to release a multimodule project with a classifier?

Tags: maven, release, maven-release-plugin

How do you release a maven multi module project if one of the submodules has a classifier?

Given this usecase:

- Multimodule project: *EAR, WAR, interface-jar, extension-AA-jar, extension-BB-jar, utility-jar*
- all the JAR's have to be build only once (or at least only be once deployed to the repository, as deploying the same artifact with the same version is forbidden)
- The WAR has to be build for two different setups, once with extension-AA-jar and once with extension-BB-jar
- only the single *extension-XX-jar* makes the difference of these two builds
- I would like to distinguish the two final artifacts in the repository by classifiers (AA|BB)
- There should also be two EARs containing only one of the WAR's (also identified by the same classifier)
- I don't want additional projects for the two WARs/EARs, as the content would be 100% the same.

So the goal is to have the following in the repository at the end (after two release:prepare, release:perform):

> - EAR-1-AA.ear
> - EAR-1-BB.ear
> - WAR-1-AA.war
> - WAR-1-BB.war
> - interface-1.jar
> - extension-1-AA.jar
> - extension-1-BB.jar
> - utility-1.jar

There are many explanations on how to do a release build and there are also examples of how to use classifier - but the classifier seems never to be used in a multimodule setup.

Note: The first release will usually not be an issue, as there is no artifact with the new version deployed yet. But doing a release for the second classifier will brake the whole thing, as maven would try to build and deploy the jars again with the same version and a the repository will (hopefully) not allow it. This is not an issue for the WAR and EAR, as the classifier is taken into account to uniquely identify the artifact

Or are classifiers really only meant to be used with single module projects?

Answer (score 3):

This is quite tricky with Maven.
You may try multiple executions of the maven-[jar/war/ear]-plugins within the package phase of the maven lifecycle. In each execution you can set the different classifiers.

Additionally, in the executions of the maven-war-plugin, you can use an `<overlay>` to get the extension with the correct classifier into the WAR file. In the executions of the maven-ear-plugin you can specify the WAR file with the correct classifier as `<webModule>`.

**Example**

In the extension modules, you can configure the maven-jar-plugin like this:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>extension-AA</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>jar</goals>
          <configuration>
            <classifier>AA</classifier>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>extension-BB</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>jar</goals>
          <configuration>
            <classifier>BB</classifier>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
  ...
</build>
```

The configuration of the WAR module is quite similar:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>extension-AA</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>war</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <overlays>
          <overlay>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>extension-1</artifactId>
            <classifier>AA</classifier>
          </overlay>
        </overlays>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>extension-BB</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>war</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <overlays>
          <overlay>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>extension-1</artifactId>
            <classifier>BB</classifier>
          </overlay>
        </overlays>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

And finally, the configuration of the EAR module:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>extension-AA</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>ear</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <classifier>AA</classifier>
        <modules>
          <webModule>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>war-1</artifactId>
            <classifier>AA</classifier>
          </webModule>
        </modules>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>extension-BB</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>ear</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <classifier>BB</classifier>
        <modules>
          <webModule>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>war-1</artifactId>
            <classifier>BB</classifier>
          </webModule>
        </modules>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```